# Determine if 24 hour datetime is within interval

Tags: r, posixct

Hope you can help.  Have a dataframe with date times in it. I'd like to determine if the time result occurs after hours (> 16:00). 
Is there an easy way to do this? Was planning on converting the time to seconds and then doing like this but suppose there's an easier way to do this via R.

```
datetimes <- c("2013-04-01 08:19:00", "2013-04-02 16:19:00", "2017-02-17 14:01:00", "2017-02-17 22:01:00")

as.POSIXct(datetimes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `format` and comparsion via `>=`:

```
format(datetimes,"%H") >= 16
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Assuming you have already converted via `as.POSIXct()` as shown in your question.

Even though `format` returns a character string, the comparison is safe to do with a numeric as all the single digit values are padded like `"08"`

Answer (score 1):

The lubridate package makes this really easy. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html for more info.

```
library(lubridate)
hour(as.POSIXct(datetimes))>16
```