# How to select data by the hour

Tags: r, time, split

I've been trying to split the data in 30 minute intervals, and I have not been able to find a solution to this problem, the date and time is a date_time variable. I just want to be able to make a df based off the time the date is not important

I have tried just splitting the data by formatting the date to just the time, but that also was not working.

this is what the df looks like

```
    Date_Time              S     C     P
    2016-08-02 21:14:52   20     1     1
    2016-08-02 21:26:37   35     1     2
    2016-09-07 21:31:33   28     1     8
    2016-08-25 21:46:16   23     3     4 
    2016-08-24 21:54:23   40     1     6
```

If I were to set the df to be between 21:00:00 - 21:30:00 it would look like:

```
    Date_Time              S     C     P
    2016-08-02 21:14:52   20     1     1
    2016-08-02 21:26:37   35     1     2
```

I'm new with r and coding so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378533/determine-if-24-hour-datetime-is-within-interval/42378962 or maybe even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465131/r-how-to-filter-a-timestamp-by-hour-and-minute

Comment: Stealing from the answer over there, I'd do something like - `fd <- format(dat$Date_Time, "%H:%M"); dat[fd >= "21:00" & fd <= "21:30",]`

Answer (score 0):

As the date is not important and you are interested only in time component, you can change the date to todays date. Also it looks like you are interested in half an hour interval starting from `00:00:00` to `00:30:00` and so on. We can create a sequence of `POSIXct` time intervals for the entire day and `split` the data based on that.

```
df$Date_Time1 <- as.POSIXct(format(df$Date_Time, paste0(Sys.Date(), "%T")))

split(df[-5], droplevels(cut(df$Date_Time1, 
   breaks  = seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%T"), 
                 as.POSIXct("23:59:59", format = "%T"), by = "30 mins"))))


#$`2019-05-24 21:00:00`
#        Date_Time  S C P
#1 2016-08-02 21:14:52 20 1 1
#2 2016-08-02 21:26:37 35 1 2

#$`2019-05-24 21:30:00`
#            Date_Time  S C P
#3 2016-09-07 21:31:33 28 1 8
#4 2016-08-25 21:46:16 23 3 4
#5 2016-08-24 21:54:23 40 1 6
```

This will return a list of dataframes where each dataframe are the rows which lie in that time interval. This is assuming your `Date_Time` column is already of `POSIXct` class. If it is not you need to change it first by doing.

```
df$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Date_Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We can `floor` the 'Date_Time' based on 30 minute interval and use that to `split` into `list` of `data.frame`s

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(grp = format(floor_date(ymd_hms(Date_Time), '30 min'), '%H:%M:%S')) %>% 
  group_split(grp, keep = FALSE)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Date_Time               S     C     P
#  <chr>               <int> <int> <int>
#1 2016-08-02 21:14:52    20     1     1
#2 2016-08-02 21:26:37    35     1     2

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Date_Time               S     C     P
#  <chr>               <int> <int> <int>
#1 2016-09-07 21:31:33    28     1     8
#2 2016-08-25 21:46:16    23     3     4
#3 2016-08-24 21:54:23    40     1     6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date_Time = c("2016-08-02 21:14:52", "2016-08-02 21:26:37", 
"2016-09-07 21:31:33", "2016-08-25 21:46:16", "2016-08-24 21:54:23"
), S = c(20L, 35L, 28L, 23L, 40L), C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), 
    P = c(1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```